# Lightbox2 and ScrollTo not working

Tags: scrollto, lightbox2

Im trying to use ScrollTo and Lightbox2 on the same page but the Lightbox2 JS links knock out the ScrollTo JS files.

This is what I have:

```
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#links').localScroll({
       target:'body'
    });

});

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Hope someone can help!

Kind Regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#links').localScroll({
       target:'body'
    });

});
```

I think you have a typo? You need to end this script with `</script>`